# Mirrored - Rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

Here is another rebus puzzle. What does it signify?

[image: REBUS4]

Comment: OK, have an upvote :-) It did make me think for a while, so it's better than some of the ****-easy rebus puzzles I've seen here recently!

Comment: Why the downvotes?!? This seems to be a perfectly valid rebus puzzle..

Comment: @CoolGuy - Yes it is valid but it is not interesting. My downvote is for low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It symbolises

> **`** (**backtick** or grave accent)

because the image shows a backwards tick.

Answer (score 1):

Background check. Because it is a checkmark written backwards in a neutral background setting.